# Composing bash conditions utilising both (( )) and [[ ]]

Tags: bash

Can one compose a condition utilising both `(( ))` and `[[ ]]` ?

```
if (( i == cnt )) && [[ "$invoke" ]]; then
```

Comment: It should be fine! What other issues are you seeing?

Comment: No problems but have not seen it used before.  Have been looking at the `[[ "$invoke" ]]` condition and does not seem the same as `[[-z $invoke]]`.

Comment: Read `man bash`.

Comment: Which parts exactly?

Comment: Read man bash which is 190 pages is not efficient as an answer !

Comment: It has an index, and contents, and the html version can also be searched by your browser. But www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions will do you for now. At least *scanning* the whole thing is very worthwhile, though. After 20 years, I still find something new every time I refer to it.

Comment: Read `man less` first to see what is the function of `/` key. It allows searching man pages. Learning Unix or GNU/Linux is not something done in 5 minutes. It requires time, perseverance and genuine interest.

Comment: I think the question is not very well suited to this Q&A style site. Couldn't you just try it? And if it works and you're still curios, you may ask for the mechanism (why is it working). Then, someone could give a comprehensive and long answer or at least point you to a good help site with explanation how `if...then...else` works in bash. But as is stands, the answer would be just "yes". (But I also think, that comments like RTFM are not very helpful ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

`if...then...else...fi` in `bash` will evaluate the return value of the part after `if`. It does not care if it's a command (e.g. `[[`, `grep`), a builtin (e.g. `test`, `[`) or a `bash` construct (e.g. `((...))`) or any of them combined using `&&` / `||`.

Comment: I would put `[[...]]` in the category of shell constructs, since it follows special syntax. `type [[` marks it as a keyword, though, the same as `if`. Which also reminds me that you can even put a compound command inside an `if` condition, e.g. another `if`, if you ever come up with a way for that to make sense...

Comment: @ilkkachu, both `((...))` and `[[ ... ]]` are classified as *compound command* in `bash`. Between `if` and `then`, you can put any amount of shell code as long as it's syntactically valid on its own. With bash and a few other shells, that code must have at least one command (of any type). It's the exit status of the last command run by that code that determines whether the `then` or the `else`/`elif` part is run.